# force SHBrowseForFolder() to show desired directory

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog, directory

I've been searching online and fighting this thing for over an hour and still can't seem to get it to work. Most people seem to be satisfied when they get it this far on forums etc. but mine still doesn't work.
I'm trying to force the SHBrowseForFolder() function to start in a folder of my choosing.

```
char current[MAX_PATH];
strcpy(current,"C:\\Users");

char outbuf[MAX_PATH];
BROWSEINFO bis;
bis.hwndOwner = NULL;
bis.pidlRoot = NULL;
bis.pszDisplayName = outbuf;
bis.lpszTitle = (LPCSTR)"HERE";
bis.ulFlags = BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE|BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS;
bis.lpfn = NULL;
bis.lParam = (LPARAM)current;

SHBrowseForFolder(
    &bis
);
```

It seems like this should be a relatively simple task. :/
At the moment, the above code is still showing the default: the Desktop folder.
Beyond starting in a specific folder, if possible, I'd also like it to ONLY show that folder and below, with no access to parent directories.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

You can also send a `BFFM_SETSELECTION` message from your `BrowseCallbackProc`, like:

```
int FAR PASCAL BrowseNotify(HWND hWnd, UINT iMessage, long wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{   if (iMessage == BFFM_INITIALIZED)
    {   SendMessage(hWnd, BFFM_SETSELECTION, 1, (LPARAM) szInitialPathName);    // Set initial folder
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `BFFCALLBACK` (lpfn) to a `BrowseCallbackProc`.  From there you can call `SendMessage` with `BFFM_SETEXPANDED` to specify the path of a folder to expand in the Browse dialog box.

See: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773205(v=vs.85).aspx and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762598(v=vs.85).aspx

From my experience, that folder dialog is a bit flaky - it often scrolls the desired directory out of view and looks suboptimal.  Just one of the joys of Windows...

Also, there is no way I have discovered to get it to show only that directory and its subs.  The parent directories always seem to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Set BIF.PidlRoot to the PIDL you don't want the user to browse below, select and expand the folder you want initially focused and selected - do as above - and it should work.

Jens. :)